# how to add a width css to table column (html table) for email template in outlook?

Tags: html, css, outlook, email-templates

I want to add width to the column (HTML table) for developing a email template for Outlook. But when I add the property it does not reflect in the email. I have tried doing the below things.

```
<table
  cellspacing="0"
  cellpadding="0"
  style="table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%"
>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: #1890ff">
      {% for item in first_table_column_names %}
      <td
        width="30%"
        style="border: 1px solid #000000; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px"
      >
        {{item.name}}
      </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have also done

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="580" style="background-color: #0290ba;">
```

This thing does not work in Outlook Application in PC and the table gets distorted. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the html mailer by nesting tables.

Please find the the below code. This may help you.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: #1890ff">
      {% for item in first_table_column_names %}
      <td width="100%" style="border: 1px solid #000000; color: #ffffff; padding: 5px">
        <table cellspacing="0"cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td style="width:30%;background-color:red;">
              {{item.name}}
            </td>
          </tr>
          
        </table>
      </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this solution, it works properly in development mode. But the result is the same in Outlook.